# Unexpected end of file in PHP code

Tags: php, html

Can anyone understand why I might be getting the following error:

> syntax error, unexpected end of file in D:\wamp\www\main\index.php on line 70

I would also appreciate it if anyone could suggest an good editor which is better for php syntax.

```
<?php
    $mysql_host='localhost';
    $mysql_user='root';
    $mysql_pass='';
    $error="Not getting connected";

    mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass) || die();
    mysql_selectdb('registration');

    if(!isset($_POST['username'])&&!isset($_POST['password']))
    {
        $error="no values has been set";
    }
    else
    {
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        $password_hash=md5($password);
        $query="SELECT * 'username','password' FROM 'registration' where 'username'='$username' AND 'password'='$password_hash'";

        if($query_run=mysql_query($query))
        {
            $query_num_rows=mysql_num_rows($query_run);

            if($query_num_rows==0)
            {
                echo "error";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "LOGGED IN";
            }
?>  



<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
   <head>
    <title>Get to know yourself</title>

   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
   <body>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <form action="index.php" method="POST" name="Registration">
            <input type="text" value="Name" Name="username">
               <input type="password" value="passowrd" Name="password">
                  <input type="submit">
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>   



      </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This post is like a specially crafted downvote magnet.

Comment: You're probably missing a `;`, a `}` or a `)`.  Double-check your code.

Comment: I wonder if using the username `' OR 1=1--` log me in?

Comment: @NickR: Don't you mean `' OR 1=1 -- `? :-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes, probably :)

Comment: Logging in? Just drop all tables lol root access baby!

Comment: Such questions as these in `java` tag actually gets upvoted ;)

Comment: @hanleyhansen ah good old xkcd - https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: What's the point of hashing passwords with md5? To be annoying?

Comment: It is always important to follow good code indention techniques. If you had your code properly indented, you could have easily seen that you were missing closing brackets.

Comment: Guys its just a rough basic sample design.I know about sql attack so keep you 'OR 1=1-- with yourself

Comment: Then presumably you would also know about `mysql_*` being deprecated - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php and also never to trust user input :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to close two braces ..!

```
}
else
{
    echo "LOGGED IN";
}
} //<--- Here (for your `if` statement)
} //<--- and Here (for your `else` statement)

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
it will work the problem is u dint close the if loop


<?php


    $mysql_host='localhost';
    $mysql_user='root';
    $mysql_pass='';
    $error="Not getting connected";

    mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass) || die();
    mysql_selectdb('registration');

    if(!isset($_POST['username'])&&!isset($_POST['password']))
    {
      $error="no values has been set";
    }
    else
    {
      $username=$_POST['username'];
      $password=$_POST['password'];
      $password_hash=md5($password);
      $query="SELECT * 'username','password' FROM 'registration' where 'username'='$username' AND 'password'='$password_hash'";
      if($query_run=mysql_query($query))
      {
       $query_num_rows=mysql_num_rows($query_run);
        if($query_num_rows==0)
        {
          echo "error";
        }
        else
        {
          echo "LOGGED IN";
      }
      }

     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing two closing curly braces for the if/then being  if($query_run=mysql_query($query))

```
    if($query_run=mysql_query($query))
    {
        $query_num_rows=mysql_num_rows($query_run);
        if($query_num_rows==0)
        {
            echo "error";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "LOGGED IN";
        }
    }
}
```

I have a feeling this question will be closed quickly though...  good luck